# Django REST API - re-use data form a single call like in Backbone.js

Tags: django, rest, django-views, tastypie

I have set up a plain vanilla Django app (no backbone.js or other MVC framework) and integrated Tastypie.

Essentially, all the information I will require on every page is available from a single call to the API. Certain pages such as "mysite.com/cityA" would simply filter that information to only that of city A's.

I am used to using backbone.js where a single collection can be shared by multiple views. How could I do this in plain Django? Would I do the call within an 'index.html' templates, from which I extend the other templates? I'm a little confused as to best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically in Django, you would write a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/), then render it and include URLs in the templates. Backbone can reuse all requested data, because it usually does not need to make a HTTP roundtrip when the user uses the application as a typical interaction with Django would work.

I would say that the default interaction models are different. If you have a database in the backend, you might want to resort to some kind of caching in your Django view - that would cut response times (but you'll keep the HTTP roundtrip). You could use some client side cache (e.g. via [localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)), but still, the default Django model is to oscillate between the view and the rendered templates.

Comment: I'll definitely be doing some form of caching when I start to optimize. Theoretically, could I manipulate the data from the single call within my views, and return the subsets as needed? I feel that it'd be best to cache the data from the single call - maybe at the tastypie level - and then have the views manipulate that single call, which itself is quite small, and again, would contain all I ever need.